# How to validate Date?

Tags: hibernate, validation

I am making a project in *Spring and Hibernate using Annotations in eclipse*.I have a `Command` Object where i have properties like `name, start-date, end-date` etc.The data type for start-date and end-date is Date.

**How to validate these date fields??**

If i enter date in the format "`yyyy-mm-dd`" it is accepted as i have specified it using `@InitBinder` ,else it throws exception.

I want to validate those Date fields and want to display error msgs as-

1. Please enter the date, don leave blank.
2. Enter date in proper format.
3. End date should be greater than start-date.

which annotations should i use, or in what other way can i do this??

Comment: What framework do you use to convert the String values from the UI into properties for the command object=

Comment: why so many ellipses and multiple question mark. If a question is visually appealing, people are likely to read it.

Comment: @Aaron- I am using @InitBinder in my Controller and here is how i have used it.                                                                     @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        dateFormat.setLenient(false);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(dateFormat, false));
    }